# I want to use JavaScript async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, settimeout

Given the following code:

```js
function timer1(){
  return new Promise(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("1...");
    }, 1000);
  })
}
function timer2(){
  return new Promise(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("2...");
    }, 2000);
  })
}
function timer3(){
  return new Promise(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("3...");
    }, 3000);
  })
}
async function timers(){
  await timer3();
  await timer2();
  await timer1();
}
timers();
```

The output is:

```js
(After 3 seconds..)
3...
```

I want to get this result:

```js
(After 3 seconds..)
3...
(After 2 seconds..)
2...
(After 1 seconds..)
1...
```

Why is only one(3...) printed?
I want to print out all three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to resolve the `Promise` when it's finished. Otherwise, it's never considered to be done, remaining forever in a pending state, and `timer2` will never be executed.

The function passed to the `Promise` constructor gets passed two parameters, which are functions to call to either terminate successfully or with a failure.

```js
function timer1(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("1...");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  })
}
function timer2(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("2...");
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  })
}
function timer3(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("3...");
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  })
}
async function timers(){
  await timer3();
  await timer2();
  await timer1();
}
timers();
```

Comment: Why is only 3... printed when the promise is forever in the pending state?

Comment: @ezhupa99 `timer3` sets the `setTimeout`, which executes. But the `Promise` itself is not resolved, so `await timer3()` never completes, and `timer2` does not start.

Answer (score 6):

you need to resolve the promise after setTimout is executed

```js
function timer1() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("1...");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function timer2() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("2...");
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function timer3() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("3...");
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });
}

async function timers() {
  await timer3();
  console.log("(After 3 seconds..)");
  await timer2();
  console.log("(After 2 seconds..)");
  await timer1();
  console.log("(After 1 seconds..)");
}

timers();
```